# Problems with escaped literal in Swift print( ) statements

Tags: swift

I like to "quote" interpolated variables in my print() statements using an escaped double quote so that they stand out better in console output. For example:

```
let num = 2 
print("\"\(num)\"")
```

prints out

```
"2"
```

However I've noticed a compiler parsing problem whenever I do this. Xcode doesn't report any compiler bugs *per se* and I can run the code just fine, but I can't double-click on any braces or parentheses in my code during editing to locate the other end of a matching pair without Xcode giving me an annoying "ding" and refusing to show the matching brace. This makes it hard to debug scope-related problems when I'm several several braces deep in a routine.

The workaround is easy: just include an extra space between the escaped quote and the start of the interpolated variable, as in

```
print("\" \(num)\"")
```

but this is somewhat less than optimal, since my quoted variables now print out thusly:

```
" 2"
```

and look odd. But at least I can continue to use brace- and parenthesis-matching to help resolve scope-related issues.

I'm presuming this is a bug that should be reported. Does anyone have suggestions though for a workaround that would fix the 'ding' problem without effecting the appearance of the output I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following workaround will help you. It just appends the strings together to achieve the desired results without the wonkiness in the text editor.

```
let num = 2 
print("\"" + "\(num)" + "\"")
```